# Weird behavior of MySQL Server when ordering by 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Say a database table `my_table` has the following structure:

```
| id      | positive_votes | total_votes | ... |
|---------|----------------|-------------|-----|
| integer | integer        | integer     | ... |
```

and some of the rows in the database have `total_votes == 0`.

I want to get the rows ordered like [this](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html), except I also want to include the rows that have `total_votes == 0`. I tried using the following query, and it worked like a charm:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
ORDER BY
    total_votes = 0,
    ((positive_votes + 1.9208) / total_votes - 1.96 * SQRT((positive_votes * (total_votes - positive_votes)) / total_votes + 0.9604) / total_votes) / (1 + 3.8416 / total_votes) DESC
```

My question is why don't I ever get a `Divide by zero` error?

I'm using `8.0.25 MySQL Community Server`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by the SQL mode.  As described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_error_for_division_by_zero), `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO` behaves as:

> - If this mode is not enabled, division by zero inserts NULL and produces no warning.
> - If this mode is enabled, division by zero inserts NULL and produces a warning.
> - If this mode and strict mode are enabled, division by zero produces an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, division by zero inserts NULL and produces a warning.

[You can see this behavior using a direct `1/0`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54c71ff6608c9121eb6df549e9cdbb07).